# Quick clarification: Justification for properties implying the zero function

Tags: functions

I came across a result that claims for a function $f(x)$ that

1. $f(x + \frac{1}{n}) = f(x)$
2. $f(x) = 0, \hspace{2mm} \forall x \in [0, \frac{1}{n})$

then $f(x) = 0,$ $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Is the reasoning here that, putting 0 in for $x$ in the left hand side of line 1 gives $f(1/n) = 0$, then all of [1,2] can be shown to be 0 from there, then [2,3] etc.. Everything just kinda falls like dominoes? Is there a slick way to formalize this?

If its relevant, this was the function

$$f(x) = \lfloor nx \rfloor - \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\lfloor x + \frac{i}{n} \rfloor.$$

Comment: What is $n$? Is the statement true for all values of $n$, or does there exists some $n$ for which this is true? Please clarify...

Comment: for any positive integer $n$, apoligies.

Comment: All you need is some fixed value of $n$.

Comment: You can replace 2. by $f(x) = 0, \hspace{2mm} \forall x \in [0, 1)$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

You can prove that $f(x) =0, \forall x \in [m, m+1), m \in \mathbb{Z}$ using induction by m. First, consider $ m \in \mathbb{N}$ etc.

**OBS**

The condition 1. can be replaced by: $f(x + 1) = f(x)$ - obtained for $n=1$.

The condition 2. can be replaced by: $f(x) =0, \forall x \in [0, 1)$ - obtained for $n=1$.

**A quicker solution:**

Inductively extend $f(x + 1) = f(x)$ to $f(x + k) = f(x), k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Now, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ then $x=[x] + \{x\}$. It follows $f(x)=f([x] + \{x\})=f(\{x\})=0$.

Comment: Perhaps I am misreading the question, but I would have thought the inductive hypothesis was on the interval $\left[\dfrac{m}{n}, \dfrac{m+1}{n}\right)$

Comment: @Henry See my edited answer.

Comment: obs? ... observe? @EugenCovaci

Comment: @PrinceM Observation

Comment: I just finished what I believe is the full proof for this identity. I am going to type it up and post for critique in a moment. But, for clarification, are you saying observe that after the proof by induction those two condition hold true or are you saying that those two condition hold in general and can be used in the inductive argument? @EugenCovaci

Comment: @PrinceM You don't need those conditions to be true in general, it is enough for them to be true only for $n=1$ in order to get $f(x) \equiv 0$